# Read file inside source folder without giving full PATH

Tags: java, file, filereader

How can I read a file (*.txt), which is located inside of the folder where my Main.java is located, without giving the full pathname

(TestApp>src>main>java>testapp>README.txt) with testapp being the source folder. When I do:  `File file = new File("README.txt");` it doesn't seem to work, but when I give the full path it works, since this varies from OS to OS it is quite inefficient is there a workaround to this? Since I don't have any idea where users are gonna extract the files and run them.

System: OSX Big Sur

IDE: NetBeans

Java: Java 17

```
import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.Desktop;  
import java.io.*;  


import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;   

/**
 * BlinMaker is a cooking assistant designed to help you shop for groceries and
 * help you discover new recipes according to you taste, available time and
 * budget all in your computer. * Copyright (C) 2021 Habis Muhammed
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
 * Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later
 * version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more
 * details.
 *
 * @author Habis Muhammed
 */
public class Main {

    /*
     * @param args the command line arguments
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        
        
        
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
        String version = model.getVersion();
        System.out.println("Welcome to BlinMaker ver " + version);
        System.out.println("""
                           BlinMaker  Copyright (C) 2021  Habis Muhammed
                               This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show w'.
                               This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
                               under certain conditions; type `show c' for license. Or press enter to continue""");
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        keyIn.nextLine();
        System.gc();
        String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        System.out.println(username);
        //INTRO ENDS

        System.out.println("Starting setup...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        budget(keyIn, username);
    }

    public static int budget(Scanner a, String username) {
        File file = new File("/NOTICE.txt");
        String[] countries = {"ITALY", "FRANCE", "USA", "UK", "JAPAN", "SPAIN", "MEXICO", "SOUTH KOREA", "KOREA", "REPUBLIC OF KOREA", "SWITZERLAND", "GERMANY", "SWEDEN", "DENMARK", "CHINA", "BRAZIL", "CANADA", "SINGAPORE", "AUSTRALIA", "GREECE", "NETHERLANDS", "NEW ZEALAND", "MEXICO", "INDIA", "SRI LANKA", "CENTRAL AFRICA", "WEST AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA", "NORTH AFRICA", "SOUTH AFRICA", "TURKEY", "NONE"};
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter your country: (Why do you need this info? Please type \"README\", type \"NONE\" if you want all reccomendations)");
        String country = a.nextLine();
        country = country.toUpperCase();
        switch (country) {
            case "README":
                openFile(username,a, file);
            //username);
        }
        System.out.println(country);

        System.out.println("Please enter your monthly budget");
        int budget = a.nextInt();
        return budget;
    }

    public static void openFile(String username, Scanner a, File file) {
        ///Users/lamna/NetBeansProjects/BlinMaker/NOTICE.txt
        //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Main obj = new Main();
        Class class1 = obj.getClass();
        URL myUrl = class1.getResource("/Users/lamna/NetBeansProjects/BlinMaker/src/main/java/blinmaker/NOTICE.txt");
        System.out.println(myUrl);
        /*try {
            //constructor of file class having file as argument  
            //File file = new File("/Users/"+username+"/NetBeansProjects/BlinMaker/NOTICE.txt");
            if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported())//check if Desktop is supported by Platform or not  
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot read file!");
                a.nextLine();
                
                return;
            }
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (file.exists()) //checks file exists or not  
            {
                desktop.open(file);              //opens the specified file  
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

NOTE: Edited code according to suggestions by commentors

Comment: Can you try printing ```file.getAbsolutePath()``` to see what it prints?

Comment: It prints /NOTICE.txt, I am thinking of creating separate releases for different OSs since I searched everywhere and couldn't find a result

Comment: Refer to method `getResource` in class `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: I did this `Main obj = new Main();
        Class class1 = obj.getClass();
        URL myUrl = class1.getResource("README.txt");
        System.out.println(myUrl);` It gave me the output 'null'

Comment: Put file `NOTICE.txt` in the same directory as file `Main.class` (note ___.class___ and not _.java_) and use the following code: `URL myUrl = getClass().getResource("NOTICE.txt");`

Comment: Yes, it does recognize the file it outputs: file:/Users/me/NetBeansProjects/BlinMaker/src/main/java/blinmaker/NOTICE.txt , but only works when I manually compile it without the Package and External Maven repositories, incredibly inconvienient but guess I'll have to live with it